# Sharing swift code over multiple projects

Tags: xcode, swift, ios7, dynamic-library

So we have a few projects that share code, and they have to remain compatible to at least iOS7 for now.

Currently we use local cocoapods to share code between different applications. This has the downside that all shared code is being put in one group. Furthermore, the Cocoapods team explained why swift pods will not be available to iOS7 projects:

> CocoaPods only supports Swift on OS X 10.9 and newer, and iOS 8 and
>   newer.
>
> Here's why:
>
> Swift is supported on OS X 10.9 / iOS 7 and newer, as stated by Apple
>   numerous times. There is no support for building static archives with
>   Swift. Dynamic frameworks are supported on all versions of OS X.
>   Dynamic frameworks are unsupported on iOS versions prior to 8:
>
> ld: warning: embedded dylibs/frameworks only run on iOS 8 or later.

(Source: http://blog.cocoapods.org/Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks/)

Given this information, we want to try and share the code using a `Cocoa Touch Framework`-project.

What I did was:

- In the workspace, create a new project -> `Cocoa Touch Framework`
- Add/Move swift code here and define needed functions/etc as `public`
- In the main build target, add the new project as an "Embedded Framework"
- Where you need to use classes from the defined library, use an import statement where the build target name is the module name (in my case `import Cobra`)

This seems to work, also on iOS7. Which is strange because everywhere online I read this warning makes sure the app won't run on iOS7 devices:

```
embedded dylibs/frameworks only run on iOS 8 or later
```

However, for us it seems to work fine on our iOS 7 testing devices.  Furthermore, this concerns me:

[image]

The frameworks path seems directly link against my local DerivedData folder. I didn't specifically choose my DerivedData folder, I just added the suggested framework from within Xcode, and it decided by itself to grab it from my DerivedData folder.
We work on this project with multiple programmers.

### TL;DR;

Before I go down this path and move code to this new setup:

- Wil this way of embedding a shared library cause problems for my team? (in other words: am I doing something wrong?)
- Will this way of embedding libraries cause any problems when submitting the app to the App Store?
- If needed: is there any alternative to way to share the code between the projects without simply copying code/files back and forth? I can't believe nobody else has this problem.

Comment: I recommend you to use `GIT` directly, avoiding the additional headaches which _cocoapod_ will give you anyway; you don't need to worry about which version of Xcode, OSX, or iOS would supports is – it supports properly everything you need and procedure of setting up and using it is much easier than wasting time for _cocoapods_, that is not really for professionals but for nerdy geeks in my view. (I don't want to start any debate, thanks, as I told "in my view"!)

Comment: Cocoapods does have the advantage it'll fix your project config to add the new sources for you. When working with something like a GIT submodule you'll have to manage this kind of stuff manually. Personally I think wanting to manage trivial stuff like this manually seems more of a geeky task ;).

Answer (score 5):

## Update 02-03-2015:

In order to share code internally, I recommend using git submodules, which require that you commit your code in a hosted repository, which can be either public or private.

---

#### Git Submodules

This is a way to distribute code stored in a repository to anyone with access. It has the benefit that you can push changes to the repository, which other consumers can then choose to update their own submodule repositories. It requires Git to be used as the project's source control and also requires the code to be pushed to a repository that the consumers have access to.

To use the code as a git submodule, you add the repository of the code to your git controlled project using the command:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/user/submoduleProject
```

replacing `https://github.com/user/submoduleProject` with your own repository URL.

Once this has been added you can then use the commands of:

```
git submodule init
```

and

```
git submodule update
```

to pull the code from the repository into the users workspace.

If you want to add any changes or updates to the submodule, you can do this and push it to the repository. Users can then update their code using `git submodule update` to obtain the latest changes.

More information on git submodules can be found at the official [documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

I hope this helps.

---

The app will not be accepted by Application Loader or Xcode when submitting to the App Store if a dynamic framework is used on an app that supports anything less than iOS 8. This is unfortunate because, as you said, it does work for iOS 7 when testing on a device.

The best way I can think of for you to share your code with your team is to hand over a folder of the code and include it in the project rather than including a dynamic framework. If you wish to keep the name spacing consistent so that in the future you can use the dynamic framework and migrate away from iOS 7, I recommend using an struct around the public methods and classes to obtain the namespace. For example:

```
public struct MyFrameworkName {
    public func doSomethingAmazing() {
         // Code...
    }

    public class DecentClass: NSObject {
         // Code..
    }

    public var terribleString: String
}
```

This will allow you to call the methods inside of the rest of the Application in the same way as with a Dynamic Framework

```
var myObject = MyFrameworkName.DecentClass()
myObject.doMethod()

MyFrameworkName.doSomethingAwesome()

MyFrameworkName.terribleString = "HEY";
```

---

In answer to your concern about linking to the framework directly from the derived data directory, this is generally an incorrect approach.

Ideally, you'd copy the framework into the project directory and then link against that version. This allows you to distribute the project's source directory to other people and the framework will remain at the correct location, relative to the project's source folder.

I hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: Well it partly helps, but my biggest problem remains: sharing code. I have to say, simply copying and pasting code cannot be considered viable solution. All the involved projects evolve pretty quickly so this would become a nightmare. There has to be some way to share code over projects without either killing Swift support or killing iOS 7 support?

Comment: You're correct, copy and pasting isn't the best solution. I'd recommend using either a private cocoapods repository or git submodules. I shall update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: those options were kind of what i was hoping for. However, cocoapods does not (can not?) support swift under iOS7 as they are using dynamic frameworks as wel? And if you just add files using git submodules, how would new files be detected to be added to the 'Compile Source'? Or would this mean manually adding new files?

Comment: That's correct. Cocoapods is not suitable for swift in this instance, therefore I recommend git submodules. 

In regards to how you wish to detect new files etc. You could create a script that automatically adds them to the compile sources. I've not personally tried this approach so I can't comment on it. The most reliable, but unfortunately encumber-some, approach would be to automatically add the files to the compile sources for the target. I understand this may seem like a nuisance, but unfortunately supporting iOS 7 really limits the options available.

Answer (score 0):

git submodules will work.  They can be a pain to work with.

If you don't want to use them, I came up with a workaround that uses a second "dummy" project with cocoapods, to pull in Swift code without requiring a Framework.

https://medium.com/@mishagray/how-to-use-swift-cocoapods-and-still-support-ios-7-0-f9dc29b3628b

Comment: Your example git repo is basically empty.

Comment: sorry about that.  The repo is up-to-date now!